# The "mod_owa" module is encountering an error: "Character string buffer too small ORA-06512: at 'SYS.HTP'."

Tags: oracle, mod-plsql

In our application, currently in mode_plsql, our website is working fine. However, during the migration to AWS, we are using mod_owa on Apache HTTP server. Unfortunately, we are encountering the following error:

"-6502 ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small ORA-06512: at 'SYS.HTP', line 1531 ORA-06512: at 'SYS.HTP', line 1758 ORA-06512: at 'XXX_XXX', line 15076"

we checked with small bit of code still we have same issue

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE]. Without any sample code and only an out-of-context error message it is probably impossible to tell you where the problem is. If you want an answer then we need code to debug.

Comment: Thank you for providing the additional information. I have added the line owa.num_cgi_vars := 0; to my code, and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is related to the output buffer size, you can adjust the buffer settings in the mod_owa configuration.

Please find the document., it may helpful to you.

https://oracle.github.io/mod_owa/modowa.htm